# Target class [TutorialController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

**Target class [TutorialController] does not exist.**

### routes/web.php

```
Route::get('user', [TutorialController::class, 'index'])->name('user.index');
Route::post('user', [TutorialController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
```

### Form

```
<form action="{{ route('user.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
```

### app/http/controllers/TutorialController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest as Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
class TutorialController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {

        return $request;
    }
}
```

### app/http/Request/CreateUserRequest.php

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ];
    }
}
```

## Add on top, TutorialController in web.php file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TutorialController;
```

I'm expecting to work. I got this tutorial on this site:
https://www.laravelia.com/post/laravel-10-form-validation-using-form-request-class

Comment: Can you run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize:clear` commands respectively and check?

Comment: composer dump-autload and php artisan optimize:clear. All working. same issue

Comment: everything in that tutorial seems to be working fine from my end

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create and run the project from the link you have provided, double check the paths specially the views i had to create app.blade while welcome.blade exists where you generated the different components, these are the relative paths for the created files (btw use the code in the link)

1. routes/web.php

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\TutorialController;
    
    Route:
:get('user', [TutorialController::class, 'index'])->name('user.index');
    Route::post('user', [TutorialController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
```

2. app/Http
   /Controllers/TutorialController.php

```
    <?php
    

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest as Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    
    class TutorialController extends Controller
    {   
        public function index()
        {
            return view('welcome');
        }
        

        public function store(Request $request)
        {   
            return $request;
        }

    }
```

3. app/Http/Requests/CreateUserRequest.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Requests;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    

    class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
      


   * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array<string, mixed>
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|min:6'
            ];
        }
    }
```

4. resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    
    @push('style')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background: gray; color:#f1f7fa; font-weight:bold;">
                        Create New User
                        <a href="{{ route('user.index') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs py-0 float-end">Back</a>
                    </div>
                    @if($errors->any())
                        {!! implode('', $errors->all('<div class="text-red">:message</div>')) !!}
                    @endif
                     <div class="card-body">                    
                        <form class="w-px-500 p-3 p-md-3" action="{{ route('user.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control  @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                                    @error('name')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control  @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block text-white">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

5. resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php (**layouts folder and app.blade.php must be created**)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        @stack('style')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        Laravelia
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
    
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
    
                        </ul>
    
                        <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                            @guest
                                @if (Route::has('login'))
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endif
    
                                @if (Route::has('register'))
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endif
                            @else
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                    </a>
    
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            {{ __('Logout') }}
                                        </a>
    
                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                            @csrf
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            @endguest
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    
            <main class="py-4" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                @yield('content')
            </main>
        </div>
        @stack('script')
    </body>
    </html>
```